# how do i access deeply nested json object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

Here, I am suppose to access the top level market details from the Json data on the first page which I'm able to although Im not able to access the sub level market details. Im suppose to display the sub level market names on the next page.

```
$scope.myData = {
  "market": [{
    "mid": 3,
    "mname": "mark1",
    "submarket": [{
      "id": 20,
      "name": "val1"
    }, {
      "id": 24,
      "name": "val2",
      "submarket": [{
        "id": 26,
        "name": "val21"
      }]
    }]
    "market": [{
      "mid": 4,
      "name": "mark1.1",
      "submarket": [{....
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "mid": 6,
    "mname": "mark2",
  }]
};

$scope.markname = []; /*stores top level markets*/
angular.forEach($scope.myData.market, function(org) {
  $scope.markname.push(org)
}) /*works fine and has the details of market (mid:3 and mid:6)*/

$scope.submark = [];
angular.forEach($scope.markname.submarket, function(sorg) {
  $scope.submark.push(sorg)
}) /*doesn't store anything*/
```

Comment: `markname` is an array, it has no property `submarket` to iterate over, that would also be more noticeable if you used the native `forEach` instead of angulars `forEach`. Angulars version handles being passed undefined, whereas the native wont work if you call it of an undefined object, you'd get a type error.

Comment: pretty much cleared! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
  $scope.submark = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.markname, function(sorg) {
    angular.forEach(sorg.submarket, function(subsorg) {
      $scope.submark.push(subsorg)
    });
  });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/y0t3eksb/1/)

Comment: this 1 works. Thanks. but the thing is, this array will store the details of sub level markets of all the main markets. what i want to do is display the sub markets of only that market that i choose to see (in the index all the top level market names are listed as options). What will help me achieve that

Comment: Play with `ng-repeat` and `ng-show` in HTML code taking the full `myData.market` array

Comment: Or either [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array in your controller or use an `ng-repeat` with an angular [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) in your view.

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.markname` is an array and your pushing items into it on your first `forEach`, however in the second your trying to access the property `submarket`. This doesn't exist on the `markname` array, it exists on each item within the array.

Ive done my example using the native `forEach` there's no need for angular to get involved here at all, it also hides the undefined issue, as the native is available of the array prototype it throws an exception if you try to call it of `undefined`, whilst angular happily accepts `undefined` and continues.

So a simple fix would be

```
markname.forEach(function(sorg) {
    if (sorg.hasOwnProperty('submarket')) {
        submark.push(sorg.submarket);
    }
});
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0y6r0mw1/

---

edit: Its worth noting this will produce a multidimensional array, if this is not wanted you can concat them all together with something like:

```
submark.push.apply(submark, sorg.submarket);
```

Answer (score 0):

The json data that you have shared, is improper. Please go through this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/qvbbg9oy/).

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myData = {
        "market": [{
            "mid": 3,
            "mname": "mark1",
            "submarket": [{
                "id": 20,
                "name": "val1"
            }, {
                "id": 24,
                "name": "val2",
                "submarket": [{
                    "id": 26,
                    "name": "val21"
                }]
            }, {
                "mid": 4,
                "name": "mark1.1",
                "submarket": [{
                    "id": 27,
                    "name": "val221"
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "mid": 6,
            "mname": "mark2",
        }]
    };

    $scope.markname = []; /*stores top level markets*/
    angular.forEach($scope.myData.market, function (org) {
        $scope.markname.push(org)
    }) /*works fine and has the details of market (mid:3 and mid:6)*/

    console.log('markname', $scope.markname);

    $scope.submark = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.markname, function (sorg) {
        angular.forEach(sorg.submarket, function (subM) {
            $scope.submark.push(subM)
        })
    })

    console.log('submark', $scope.submark);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function iterate(obj) {
    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
                iterate(obj[property]);
            }
            else {
                console.log(property + "   " + obj[property]);
           }
        }
    }
} 
iterate(object)
```